# Vertical circular motion(with gravity)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation, rotational-kinematics

Let's say I have a stone tied to a string and swing it vertically upwards. Now, if I provide an initial velocity such that the velocity of the stone = 0 at an angle greater than 0 from the horizontal(visualize it in the "first quadrant") the eq of motion would be: $T+mg\sin \theta = mv^2/r$. If the velocity equals zero, then tension would end up negative which is not possible. Hence I've come to the conclusion that as soon as The T =0(which would happen before v =0), the stone would exit circular motion and travel somewhat like a projectile. So basically, in the "first quadrant", it's not possible for v to end up 0 while remaining in circular motion since T would = 0 before V would equal 0 and hence the stone would exit circular motion. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REVISED ANSWER :

The tension in the string will become zero when
$v^2/r = gsin\theta$.
v is still +ve when this happens.  v will only become zero later.

So you are correct : first T becomes zero (which cannot happen until $\theta > 0$), then the stone moves as a projectile on a parabolic path, then v beomes zero.

Comment: I edited the question. See if you can understand it now

Comment: Alright, sounds good. 
However, "first T becomes zero (which cannot happen until θ>0)" is wrong. T can become 0 at $\theta = 0$ too, since in the "fourth quadrant", T can be positive while $v = 0$($T = mgcos\alpha + mv^2/r$ where $\alpha$ is the angle formed with the vertical) so if v ends up 0 at exactly $\alpha = 90$ or $\theta = 0$(both are equivalent), T would equal 0 too.